# Python : Custom Dependency Check

Tags: python

I have a production package that has some 50 custom necessary/un-necessary dependencies (in-house, python, rails, perl). Is there any good way to check in python for un-necessary dependencies so that I can delete them from the whole package?

Comment: What about `grep -rn dependency_name folder_with_source_code/` ? It is hard to say automatically if the dependency is necessary or not, apart from looking at the code.